# Class Constructor should only accept a certain thing as an argument otherwise throw an error

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, try-catch

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I've come across a rather frustrating issue I can't get past.

I'm doing an exercise on TwilioQuest where my constructor should only accept "red", "yellow" or "blue" as arguments, otherwise throw an error. This looks correct to me and works when testing in the console, however when I 'HACK' in game, TwilioQuest says my constructor should only accept "red", "yellow" or "blue" as arguments. Well...IT DOES

[image: This is my code mentioned above]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Your constructor happily accepts any argument at all, or indeed no arguments, because A) you're suppressing errors with `try`/`catch` (not that any are thrown), and B) you're never using `throw`.

Remove the `try`/`catch`, and add a `throw` in a final `else`. The whole point is to throw an error, abruptly terminating the constructor, and preventing anything from getting a reference to the object it was initializing.

I also suggest using `||` and only a single `if`/`else`. No point in repeating `this.color = color;` three times.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up. The exercise was pointing me towards try...catch and throw and I think I was getting confused by the difference. Also, I did have only one if...else statement originally but I was trying all sorts of different strats to try and please TwilioQuest, hence why it was spelled out explicitly as such. Changed it back now. All sorted! Thanks again!

Comment: @SharpeCode57 - Glad that helped! Please do edit your question to put your actual code there, not a picture of the code, for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly will be useful to store all valid colors in the array. In order to be able to change the list of the valid colors without updating of the logic in the constructor.

Second, we can use `Array.prototype.includes` method in order to check if the passed parameter(`color` in the code below) is an element of the array.

If we need to restrict user of our class `Ducktypium` we should `throw` Error each time when input parameter `color` is not in the list of valid colors.

Otherwise everything is fine, and we can assign parameter `color` to prop `color`

```
const VALID_COLORS = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
class Ducktypium {
   constructor(color) {
      if (!VALID_COLORS.includes(color)) {
         throw new TypeError('invalid color')
      }
      this.color = color
   }
}
```

Comment: It's good of you to try to help, but code dumps are not *useful* answers, and simply writing the code for the OP is inappropriate when they're trying to solve a coding challenge.

Comment: Would be better if you'd at least explain what you did in your code and why.

Comment: Thank you for your input, your answer along with the TJ's helped me solve the problem (fyi I didn't use the example code).